# Geolocation API - always getting - Access is denied

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, geolocation

I am using the code to get the geo-location on my site. for example
https://subdomain.domain.com/pwa

```
  <script type = "text/javascript">

     function showLocation(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        alert("Latitude : " + latitude + " Longitude: " + longitude);
     }

     function errorHandler(err) {
        if(err.code == 1) {
           alert("Error: Access is denied!");
        } else if( err.code == 2) {
           alert("Error: Position is unavailable!");
        }
     }

     function getLocation() {

        if(navigator.geolocation) {

           // timeout at 60000 milliseconds (60 seconds)
           var options = {timeout:60000};
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation, errorHandler, options);
        } else {
           alert("Sorry, browser does not support geolocation!");
        }
     }

  </script>
```

```
  <form>
     <input type = "button" onclick = "getLocation();" value = "Get Location"/>
  </form>
```

I added the above code in geoWatch.html.
when I visit the page and click on - get location. I am prompted to allow for - Geolocation, which I accept and I can see the same in settings for website the geolocation is allowed.

but immediately after I click on accept the allow notification - I get the error alert - Error: Access is denied.
I remember it was working fine, what and where I messed up, can't figure out what went wrong, so I took this sample code and put this both in pwa folder as well as in the root of the site to test, if any other code is conflicting, but it didn't helped.

Additional Note:
I installed chrome canary and there it(same code) is working fine.

Edit: Even Chrome Canary worked for the first try only. any subsequent try getting same error.
but Samsung Mobile browser working fine even after multiple tries.

Comment: Are you on https?r did you deny it? `chrome://settings/content/location`

Comment: assuming you are using Chrome, do you have a red square in the right corner of your url bar?, if so, click it and allow geolocation

Comment: @AngelSalazar - Yes I am on chrome, but I couldn't see any redbar. also as I said, when I check the site settings, I can see the geolocation is allowed.

Comment: @epascarello - yes I am on https and no I didn't denied it. but I am not able to access the link on mobile android chrome. I am trying in android mobile. but I can access the link in windows desktop chrome.

Comment: I just tested your code on chrome and it's working fine

Comment: @th31 - did you tested on chrome android mobile?

Comment: yes and it's not working :(

Comment: so it looks like it is the bug with android chrome or what?

Comment: i have no idea maybe it's related with your ssl certificate
i have uploaded your code on this website https://my-store.gq/, and it seems work fine on both chrome mobile and desktop.

Comment: I tried with - https://my-store.gq/ - I am still getting the same error. I allowed geo-location.

Comment: but in chrome canary https://my-store.gq/ is also working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem recently. In my case it is because Permissible Policy set from server for geolocation is set to (), it should be (self).

[Doc about Permission Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Permissions_Policy#relationship_with_the_permissions_api)